# Why isn't this Track To constraint working?

Tags: rigging, constraints

I'm using the [Cats](https://github.com/absolute-quantum/cats-blender-plugin) plugin to optimize this character model for vrchat! Unfortunately, getting eye tracking to work has been rough.

[image: The error message from Cats.]

**[Update 2022-5-30: This Cats feature is apparently deprecated! I still needed this question answered to get the eyes rigged though]**

I tried using a `Track To` constraint to get the `Eye_Master` bones to track the `Eye` bones, but now the eye rig is broken and the bone seemingly avoids being clicked on. I really don't know how else to describe this.

[image: The bones flailing around.]

I'm sorry this post is relatively vague, but when it comes to character modelling, rigging is what I'm least versed in.

You can find the .blend file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10hTQkP8QGcESI_eCKJJRLjS9BZTcCX5v/view?usp=sharing). Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The track-to isn't working right because it is involved in a dependency loop.

Eye_Master.L is set to track-to Eye.L.  But Eye.L is a child of Eye_Master.L.  So the rotation of Eye_Master depends on the location of Eye, which depends on the rotation of Eye_Master, which depends on the location of Eye, etc.

You have to choose whether you want Eye to be controlled by Eye_Master or if you want Eye_Master to be controlled by Eye.

Comment: Thank you so much!

I can't get this to work with a `Track To` constraint, but I can get it to work with a `Damped Track` constraint. This isn't a problem, but I'm curious as to why this is.

I've made a [video](https://youtu.be/99sceOZGQj0) to demonstrate.

Comment: In your video, you have already unparented Eye.L, different than the file you've provided; a damped track certainly will not work right if creates a dependency loop, no better than a track-to will.  The reason the track-to doesn't work in your video is because you cannot use the same track axis as up axis (and the up axis is really +-axis.)  If you want a track-to with an unparented Eye.L, set the track axis to Y.  But this is really a brand new question-- the problem in the file you gave is a dependency problem.